# updateSelectizeInput in a shiny module

Tags: r, shiny, selectize.js

I would like to use a reactive value to load control a selectizeInput widget. I can do this with a simple shiny app, but I can't seem to be able to replicate it when I try to reorganize it in a module.

In the following code I have a simple app with an input widget and a button. After pressing the button, I want the `selectizeInput()` widget to be updated with the values stored in the reactive variable.

```
library(shiny)

# GLOBAL VAR TO BE LOADED after pressing the button
# -------------
STORED <- reactiveValues(choices = c("a", "b", "c")
                         , selected = c("c"))

# UI
# -------------
ui <- fixedPage(
  wellPanel(
    # input widget
    selectInput("widget1"
                , "label"
                ,choices = c("WRONG A","WRONG B","WRONG C")
                ,selected="WRONG A"
                )

    # update button
    , actionButton("plotBtn"
                   , "update"
                   , class = "btn-primary")
  )
)

# SERVER
# -------------
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$plotBtn,{
    message("update button was pressed")

    updateSelectInput(session
                      ,"widget1"
                      ,choices = STORED$choices
                      , selected = STORED$selected
    )
  })
}

# APP
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

after pressing the button, the widget is correctly updated with "c" selected, and the choices are correctly imported. However, when I try to write it as a shiny module, the button doesn't work.

library(shiny)

```
# INIT VARS TO BE LOADED AFTER PRESSING THE BUTTON
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
STORED <- reactiveValues(choices = c("a", "b", "c")
                         , selected = c("c"))

# MODULE SELECTIZEINPUT
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
input_widgetUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)

  selectizeInput(ns("input_widget")
                 , label = "label"
                 , choices = c("WRONG A","WRONG B","WRONG C")
                 , selected = "WRONG A"
  )

}

# MODULE BUTTON
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
plotBtnUI <- function(id){

  ns <- NS(id)

  fluidPage(actionButton(ns("plotBtn"), "update", class = "btn-primary"))
}

plotBtn <- function(input, output, session) {

  ns <- session$ns

  print("Loading plotBtn()")

  observeEvent(input$plotBtn, {

    message("update button was pressed")

    updateSelectizeInput(session
                         , ns("widget1")
                         , choices = STORED$choices
                         , selected= STORED$selected
                         )

  })
}


# #############################################################################
# SHINY APP
# #############################################################################
ui <- fixedPage(
  wellPanel(
    input_widgetUI("widget1")
    , plotBtnUI("button")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  callModule(plotBtn, "button")
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I belive I might be using the wrong ID. Any suggestion is very welcome! Thanks

Comment: Why are you using modules? Can't you just put everything inside server / ui

Comment: Modules can be very hekpful at times, especially when you are working with many ids

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution is closer to what I was looking for. It still allows to keep the button and the input widget in distinct modules (i.e. have the button on a different tab for example).

```
library(shiny)
options(shiny.reactlog=TRUE)

# INIT GLOBAL VARS
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
STORED <- reactiveValues(choices = c("WRONG A","WRONG B","WRONG C")
                         , selected = "WRONG A")

# MODULE SELECTIZEINPUT
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
input_widgetUI <- function(id) {

  ns <- NS(id)

  tagList(
    selectizeInput(ns("input_widget")
                   , label = "label"
                   , choices = NULL
                   , selected = NULL
    )
  )
}

input_widgetSERVER <- function(input, output, session){

  #ns <- session$ns

  observe({

    updateSelectizeInput(session
                        , "input_widget"
                        , choices = STORED$choices
                        , selected= STORED$selected
                        , server=TRUE
                        )
  })

}

# MODULE BUTTON
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
plotBtnUI <- function(id){

  ns <- NS(id)

  fluidPage(actionButton(ns("plotBtn"), "update", class = "btn-primary"))
}

plotBtnSERVER <- function(input, output, session) {

   #ns <- session$ns

   print("Loading plotBtn()")

   observeEvent(input$plotBtn, {

     message("update button was pressed")

     # VARS TO BE LOADED AFTER PRESSING THE BUTTON
     STORED$choices <- c("a", "b", "c")
     STORED$selected <- c("c")

   })
}


# ######################################################################
# SHINY APP
# ######################################################################
ui <- fixedPage(
  tagList(
      input_widgetUI("widget1")
    , plotBtnUI("button")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  callModule(input_widgetSERVER, "widget1")
  callModule(plotBtnSERVER, "button")
}
# launch the app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 4):

you want to have the selectizeInput **and** actionButton in the same UI function. otherwise will you have different namespaces for each of them. In this case you also don't need the `ns` function in the server part. You only need that when you are rendering dynamic UI objects

Here is working version of your code

```
STORED <- reactiveValues(choices = c("a", "b", "c")
                         , selected = c("c"))

# MODULE SELECTIZEINPUT
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
input_widgetUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
  selectizeInput(ns("input_widget")
                 , label = "label"
                 , choices = c("WRONG A","WRONG B","WRONG C")
                 , selected = "WRONG A"
  ),
  actionButton(ns("plotBtn"), "update", class = "btn-primary")  
  )

}


plotBtn <- function(input, output, session) {

  ns <- session$ns

  print("Loading plotBtn()")

  observeEvent(input$plotBtn, {

    message("update button was pressed")
    updateSelectizeInput(session = getDefaultReactiveDomain()
                         , inputId = "input_widget"
                         , choices = STORED$choices
                         , selected= STORED$selected
    )

  })
}


# #############################################################################
# SHINY APP
# #############################################################################
ui <- fixedPage(
  wellPanel(
    input_widgetUI("widget1")
  )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  callModule(plotBtn, "widget1")
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!